# Download file JQuery with delegated click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

---

SOLVED: View the answer below marked SOLVED. Thanks.

---

I am trying to download a file from location specified by url on click. I am using a delegate but when the button clicks the browser navigates to the location of the file and displays the contents. I want the click to trigger the browser's download dialog.

Here is the code:

```
$('#left').delegate("a", "click", function(event){
    //alert("CLICKED");

    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = url;

});
```

All posts regarding this question says to use the "event.preventDefault();" but that does not work for me. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You cant do this using jQuery ... is the href a backend file that serves the page ? or a direct link to a file (a pdf for example) ?

Comment: It is a direct link to the file in on the webserver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to change the server side (if you are able to).

The http response must contain the header:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=fname.ext
```

So the browser knows that it must open the download dialog. Otherwise the browser will try to open/preview it.

More info:

[Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519)

Comment: You need to add this header on your backend. You can't change the response headers on the client side.

Comment: So I tried using  : "header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file_path);" in my php script that executes when I click download. But nothing happened when that line got executed.

Comment: after adding the header, what happen if you try to access the file directly with your browser? does the dialog show up?

Comment: No when I access the file directly, the browser just opens it directly  on the page. No Dialog showed up.

Answer (score 1):

---

SOLVED:
The following php script allowed prompting the browser dialog box with the file:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
$fp=fopen($filepath,'r');
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

Thank you deantoni for leading me in the correct direction =).

---

Comment: Thanks! I would be very happy if you could set my answer as accepted :D